# Select statement showing null values in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm facing a problem in my c# form, I'm populating datagridview in c#  with access database 2007 by command

```
SELECT * FROM TBLMEMBERINFO WHERE NAME LIKE 'A*';
```

this gives null value even name exist in database......

also when i have tried this command directly in access 2007 sql
view...then it works ..showing results for name starting with A...

please suggest a solution how can i populate datagridview with access2007 having name starting with A...

Comment: What is your relevant C# code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you were using sql commands did you try doing somthing like this?

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBLMEMBERINFO WHERE NAME = 'A%'";
```